# Logitech Ultimate Ears 4000 - remote doesn't work on Windows

Tags: windows, logitech-headset

I've tried using the remote (+ volume, -volume, pause) control on my headphones, but it doesn't do anything. I've tried on both Windows 7 and Windows 8. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headphones are designed with portable devices like iPods or iPhones in mind and as such, the remote control will only work with these devices.

> The remote and mic are supported only by iPod nano® (4th generation or later), iPod classic® (120 GB, 160 GB), iPod touch® (2nd generation or later), iPhone 3GS® or later, and iPad®.

Source: http://ue.logitech.com/en-nz/product/ue4000#tab-specs